# Prisma batch upsert with raw SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma

I would like to do a batch upsert for a table in postgres. Since prisma doesnt support this in its api, i have to use `$executeRaw`. I am a little stuck though on how to properly use [`Prisma.join` and `Prisma.sql`](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/raw-database-access#tagged-template-helpers) for inserting the data into the template tag.

This post seems to indicate a possible solution: https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/15452#discussioncomment-3737632, however the function signature of `Prisma.sql` is `export declare function sqltag(strings: ReadonlyArray<string>, ...values: RawValue[]): Sql;` which indicates it takes two *arrays* rather than a string.

This is what i have so far:

```
async function batchUpsertPosts(posts){
  await prisma.$executeRaw`INSERT INTO Posts (
    feedDomain,
    postId,
    title,
    score,
  )
  VALUES (), (), ()--... and so on with posts
  ON CONFLICT ("feedDomain","postId") DO UPDATE SET score = excluded.score`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I managed to figure it out.

```
async function batchUpsertPosts(posts) {
  await prisma.$executeRaw`INSERT INTO "public"."Posts" (
    "feedDomain",
    "postId",
    "title",
    "score",
  )
  VALUES ${Prisma.join(
    posts.map(post =>
      Prisma.sql`(${post.feedDomain}, ${post.postId}, ${post.title} ,${post.score})`
    )
  )}
  ON CONFLICT ("feedDomain","postId") DO UPDATE SET score = excluded.score`
}
```

So i just needed to use:

```
Prisma.sql``
```